# rna-seq user friendly pipeline recommendations

Tags: pipeline, analysis, rna-seq

I’m a new in bioinfo and rna seq analysis for human and mouse mRNA and miRNA analysis.

I used to use script pipelines workflows to do my analysis. The pipelines used fastq, cutadapt, star and bowtie2 and FeaturesCounts as softwares but I just so some people say that Cutadapt, bowtie and Star were obsolete. So I’m just without ground lol.

Majority of this script like pipelines of RNA-seq that I found are with this softwares that I already use and articles are just to divergents about the meter.

My question is true that it have better tools now? Who are they? Do you guys have a recommendation of pipelines/workflows user friendly and script-like??

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're doing well. I just wanted to ask for some clarification regarding your question. To better understand your query, could you please provide more information about the context in which your RNA-seq data is? Once we have this information, you can proceed to design a bioinformatic pipeline that can clean up your raw reads, map them against a desired reference, and calculate expression data based on the specific conditions of your experiment. Keep in mind that it's important to consider your initial wet lab conditions when establishing a reasonable pipeline for your data. While it's not necessary to use the most updated software, it's essential to think carefully about the best approach to take full advantage of your data.